# Legacy jQuery Datatables Local Caching?

Tags: sql-server, datatables

The problem I'm trying to solve is to make a table more responsive when large numbers of records are returned. The site I'm working on is using the legacy jquery datatables plugin (v1.9) and we're unable to update it at this time due to the nature of the project. 

I'm trying to avoid going the server side route since the response time of the ajax call is not an issue even after testing with an absurd amount of records, an order of magnitude more data than would be expected. What seems to be slowing the table is that every record is being loaded into the DOM and sometimes having the sorting function performed on it (when the data coming back is not already sorted in the manner the table is sorting).

Is there is a way to cache the entire dataset then perform server-side like calls but on that local cache to avoid hitting the server over and over again? And from that only populate the DOM with a manageable amount of records?

```
var prSearchResultsTable= $prSearchResults.dataTable({
    'aaSorting': [defaultSort], // no column is sorted by default
    'bJQueryUI': false,
    'iDisplayLength': 25,
    'oLanguage': {
        'sEmptyTable': 'Select search options in the form above.',
        'sZeroRecords': 'Your search matched 0 purchase requests.',
        'sSearch': 'Filter:'
    },
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
});


for(; i < data.length; i++) {
    var newRowIndex = prSearchResultsTable.fnAddData([
        data[i][0], //PO_ID
        data[i][1], //NEED BY DATE
        data[i][2], //SHIP TO LOCATION AREA ID
        data[i][3], //NOTES
        data[i][4], //CREATE USER ID
        data[i][5], //CREATE_DATE
        data[i][6]  //APPROVAL STATUS
    ]);
    var newRow = prSearchResultsTable.fnGetNodes(newRowIndex);
    newRow.setAttribute('data-sprid', data[i].id);
    newRow.setAttribute('data-sprnum', data[i].number);
    newRow.setAttribute('class', newRow.getAttribute('class') + 'dataRowHighlight');
}
```

Comment: If you're not using server-side, then the datatable should behave in the way you describe - ie sorting, page, etc is performed without a database call.  Posting the datatables initialisation code would be useful.

Comment: Using your init code, I've created a working demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/44bt9px2/) which works as I would expect your code to work. Is there something you're not showing us?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong when I populate the table. I'm looping thru the result set and running the fnAddData method on the table. Is there a way to optimize that maybe for when I have a large amount of records (1000's)

Comment: To be more specific I have a working table but I'm trying to make it more responsive in the client. It just seems like the way the table handles large amounts of records is clunky. Like when I make my data call I can get back 50k dummy records in like 400ms and log them out to the console but it'll take the browser like an hour to finish populating the table.

Comment: can you show me the line where `fnAddData()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you're calling `fnAddData()` is the problem.

According to the [fnAddData() documentation](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnAddData), there's a 2nd bool parameter which dictates whether the datatable is redrawn after each add. Because you don't pass this parameter (which defaults to true), the table is redrawn after each line which is probably why it's so slow.  Amend your code to this:

```
prSearchResultsTable.fnAddData([
        data[i][0], //PO_ID
        data[i][1], //NEED BY DATE
        data[i][2], //SHIP TO LOCATION AREA ID
        data[i][3], //NOTES
        data[i][4], //CREATE USER ID
        data[i][5], //CREATE_DATE
        data[i][6]  //APPROVAL STATUS
    ], false);
```

You'll need to call [fnDraw()](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnDraw) after the loop to draw the table.